# Standard ML: making a type transparent with opaque signature ascription

Tags: sml, signature, functor

As I understand it, in SML modules, to prevent every type from being hidden by opaque signature ascription, you can specify concrete types in the signature.

I'm trying to do that with a functor for making symbol tables, hiding the table type but leaving the entry type transparent. But whenever I do opaque ascription I can't access the entry type. Here are my signatures and functor:

```
signature ST_ENTRY = sig
    type entry
    val name : entry -> string
end

signature SYMTABLE = sig
    structure E: ST_ENTRY
    type symentry = E.entry  
    type symtable
    val empty: symtable
    val insert: symtable -> E.entry -> symtable
    val lookup: symtable -> string -> E.entry option
end

functor SymtableFn (Ent:ST_ENTRY) :> SYMTABLE = struct
  structure E = Ent
  type symentry = E.entry
  type symtable = E.entry list
  val empty: symtable = []
  fun fromList symlist = symlist
  fun insert (tab: symtable) e = e::tab
end
```

Then, when I create an entry struct and instantiate the functor with it, like this:

```
structure Myentry : ST_ENTRY = struct
  type entry = {name: string, typ: string}
  fun name (e:entry) = #name e
end

structure Mytable = SymtableFn (Myentry)
val tab = Mytable.insert (Mytable.empty) {name="x", typ="str"}
```

I get a type clash for the last line, but if I turn off opaque ascription, it works fine. I tried with both SML/NJ and Moscow ML and get the same error. Why isn't this working like I think it should? Is there any way to make the entry type transparent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to specify that the resulting type `E.entry` relates to the functor parameter. Just change the declaration of the functor to

```
functor SymtableFn (Ent:ST_ENTRY) :> (SYMTABLE where type E.t = Ent.entry) = struct ...
```

In fact, I'd drop substructure `E` from signature `SYMTABLE` and change the above to

```
functor SymtableFn (Ent:ST_ENTRY) :> (SYMTABLE where type symentry = Ent.entry) = struct ...
```

Comment: This worked great, I just needed to remove the parentheses to avoid a syntax error.  Per your suggestion, I removed the substructure from  `SYMTABLE`; I had only added it to try to solve the problem in the question.